# How can I remove all DebuggerHiddenAttribute

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

How can I remove all DebuggerHiddenAttribute from an assembly only if the compiler generated this attribute?

I'm trying this code, but it doesn't work.

```
    ModuleDefinition module = ...;
MethodDefinition targetMethod = ...;
MethodReference attributeConstructor = module.Import(
    typeof(DebuggerHiddenAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

targetMethod.CustomAttributes.Remove(new CustomAttribute(attributeConstructor));
module.Write(...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really possible.  The attributes defined in a compiled assembly are immutable.  You can't change them without reproducing the entire assembly.

In this particular answer when you call `Remove` it is being called on an array returned by the `CustomAttributes` property.  It will remove it from the array, not from the metadata on the assembly

Comment: Hi JaredPar, Thanks for reply, I think mono.cecil not full access metadata for remove attributes, If possible take a example for solved this problem, Thanks in advance.