# Why does the compiler automatically generate a Debugger attribute for anonymous type?

Tags: c#, compilation, cil

When compiling a simple anonymous type code like this:

```
public class Test
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var my_anonymous = new { Name = "anonymous"};
    }
}
```

The IL code has a Debugger attribute for every generated method of the anonymous type. e.g. for Equals:

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance bool 
          Equals(object 'value') cil managed
  {
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 )
  ... // rest of IL code
```

Why does the compiler generate it automatically? I compiled it with Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0, and (if this has any relevance) without using the VS cmd.

Note: There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151510/how-can-i-remove-all-debuggerhiddenattribute) answer for removing the attribute (not possible), but I wonder about the "Why?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) - it simply tells the Visual Studio debugger that this is a generated type, don't stop inside its code. (Because the code was not written by the user - it was generated by the compiler.)

Other debuggers are allowed to follow the same behavior - if you read the documentation, there's no semantics attached to this attribute, so all debuggers (or virtual machines) are free to interpret it any way they want (or are free to ignore it).

Answer (score 5):

Because anonymous type implementation is automatically done by the compiler and there is no point in having the debugger step through the auto generated code.

1. Because there is no bug in the generated code; it would be a compiler bug, not something specific to your code.
2. Becuse even if there was a bug you could do little about it as the class would be rewritten once you compile.
3. Because stepping through uninteresting code every time you debug is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The common language runtime attaches no semantics to this attribute.
>   It is provided for use by source code debuggers. For example, the
>   Visual Studio 2005 debugger does not stop in a method marked with this
>   attribute and does not allow a breakpoint to be set in the method.
>   Other debugger attributes recognized by the Visual Studio 2005
>   debugger are the DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute and the
>   DebuggerStepThroughAttribute.

I think this is added because code is generated in compile time not written by programmer so some lines of generated code not exist in user code and debugger cant show it.